# needs to manually update documentID and InstanceID of indesign uploaded file

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

I am using InDesignCC 2019, using zxp installer I have uploaded my zxp file for AEM extensions and uploaded my `264578_***-1F.indd` file. In InDesignCC20019 under `file/ fileInfo` I can see the all the meta data info of it. But now my requirement is that, I should be able to edit / update `DocumentID` and `InstanceID` in that meta data. Is it possible to do? If possible any directions please

Comment: Perhaps install and utilize [exiftool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) which is a a command-line application for reading, writing and editing meta information. Then run something like the following command: `exiftool -overwrite_original -xmp:InstanceID=foo -xmp:DocumentID=bar /some/path/to/file.indd` - This will change the `InstanceID` to `foo`, and also change the `DocumentID` to `bar` in the file located at `/some/path/to/file.indd` - you'll obviously need to redefine those three values as necessary.

Comment: I want to update the documentID and InstanceID in the InDesignPlugin itself.  I am looking  for the ways to modify these  through code using CEP AEM extensions, is it possible?